# С++ не могу найти ошибку

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    const int SIZE = 10;
    int arr[SIZE];
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = 0 + rand() % (20 - 0 + 1);

        for (int j = 0; j < 21; j++)
        {
            repeat:
            if ((arr[i] == arr[j])&&(i != j))
            {
                arr[i] = 0 + rand() % (20 - 0 + 1);
                goto repeat;
            }
        }
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Суть кода заключается в том что массив arr нужно заполнить случайными числами от 0 до 20 при этом чтобы они(эти числа) не повторялись.

Comment: Приводите конкретные тестовые примеры, пожалуйста. Что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, что на самом деле на выходе. Текст ошибки, если есть, и указание на строку к которой она выдана. Тогда выше шанс получить помощь.

Comment: Синтаксических ошибок нету .просто код рабртает не так какак ожидается.Иногда цифры в массиве повторяются

Comment: @Сергей, какой вход? В вопросе же целая программа, в которой считывания вообще нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy, я же не пишу текст каждый раз снова. Есть "первый вопрос" на проверку, есть стандартный ответ, если непонятно, в чем у автора конкретная проблема. Кроме того, этот даётся ответ не только на конкретный случай, но в рамках "первого вопроса"и как совет автору по оформлению вопросов в дальнейшем. (И если нет входа, то не нужно его приводить, разумеется.)

Answer (score 2):

Этот вопрос [много раз разбирался здесь, на ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9).

Но если вы хотите вот так, в лоб, с проверкой — то

```
int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 10;
    int arr[SIZE];
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        for(bool ok = true; ok; )
        {
            arr[i] = rand() % 21;
            ok = false;
            for(int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
                if (arr[i] == arr[j])
                {
                    ok = true;
                    break;
                }
        }
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Выход за границы массива:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 21; j++)
                ^^^^^^

    if ((arr[i] == arr[j])&&(i != j))
                   ^^^^^^
```

Лоджно быть `j < i`